# Conformal mapping from a tetrahedron to a spherical sector

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry

I have been trying to find a way to do a conformal mapping from tetrahedron, specifically a [trirectangular tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trirectangular_tetrahedron), to a [spherical sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector), but being an engineer with no training in this subject it seems to be a few notches too advanced for me. This [image: picture] is an attempt to illustrate the two geometries and how they are placed wrt. eachother.

Most of what I find on conformal mappings is in 2D and formulated in the complex plane, which naturally does not cover my problem. I have found that the mapping must consist of only similarity transformations and inversions, but inversions seem to be mostly applied to spherical shells (e.g stereographic projections) and not to "solid spheres."

I also need the analogous mapping in 2d, i.e. a right isosceles triangle to a disk sector where the base and one leg coincides with the sector rays, but here I assume I can use the mapping from a disc to a square using only a quarter of the disc/square. Is this correct, and when I only need this part is there a formula not involving complex numbers?

Edit:
Also, the mapping must be the identity mapping at the centre of the sphere (disk in 2d), so that the (iso-) surfaces of constant radii in the sphere are gradually changing from spherical to planar in the tetrahedron as the radial coordinate increases.

Comment: If we view the sphere as sitting on a plane, with the point of tangency at its south pole (I think this is the configuration your picture is supposed to indicate), then stereographic projection from the north pole onto the plane is already a conformal map, and in particular, it will map spherical triangles to triangles in the plane.

Comment: @travis the way I understand stereographic projection works only when you want to project the outer shell (closure?) of the sphere; whereas what I'm seeking is a mapping of the entire spherical sector, i.e. a solid 3d body, to the solid tetrahedron. Perhaps *ball* would be the appropriate term?

Comment: I see no reason to think the three dimensional problem is possible. The Riemann Mapping Theorem says any planar domain can be taken to the disk, there two such to each other, for you Schwarz-Christoffel mappings. 3D, no. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28conformal_mappings%29

Comment: @EspenM Ah, I understand now, I thought you simply wanted to map the surfaces of the two shapes. Typically one uses "sphere" just to refer to the "outer shell" and, like you suggest, "ball" to refer to the interior of the shape. Anyway, no such map exists, please see my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any map that sends the top "corner" of the "ball sector" in your picture to the top vertex of the tetrahedron in particular sends a right angle to an acute angle, and so cannot be conformal, so there is no map meeting your criteria.

Like Will Jagy says, in 2 dimensions any simply connected domain (other than $\mathbb{C}$) is analytically and hence conformally equivalent to a disc. In short there are *lots* of conformal maps, and in fact we can make more precise the statement that there is an infinite-dimensional space of conformal maps.

But, the 2-dimensional setting is wholly misleading about conformal geometry in higher dimensions, which is *much* more rigid, and where there is only a finite-dimensional space of conformal maps.

Comment: Regarding sending a right angle to an acute, I assume that you're referring to e.g. the right angle on the face "facing us" at the top "corner," which has the shape of a disk sector. I expected the mapping on the outer faces would be exactly like the 2d case (i.e. mapping between disk sector and a triangle), and this mapping do exist since we can choose a triangle from the [square](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/schwarzchristoffel/SchwarzChristoffelMod/Images/SchwarzChristoffelMod_gr_9.gif)... (I assume there are singularities at cornes "allowing" this to happen)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Like you say, one can permit failure of conformality at corners in the 2-dimensional case---more precisely, when we talk about conformal maps between sets, the sets themselves are open, so they don't include the boundary where the singularities occur. In dimensions greater than two, however, singularities can only happen in one, very controlled way, by sending a point off to infinity, so the sort of behavior you describe in 2 dimensions can't occur in higher dimensions.

Comment: One way to think about the behavior in higher dimensions is that it's a theorem of Liouville that a conformal map between two regions in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n > 2$, always extends uniquely to a global conformal map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, allowing for the possibility of at most one singularity (one point being sent to infinity).

Comment: Thank you very much @travis, I really appreciate this. Could I ask you to share some more of your insight: Why is it that 2d is in such a special position in this regard? One could perhaps hope for other even-dimensional spaces having similar properties; e.g. 4d which have the "quarternion formulation" that can be related to complex numbers?

Comment: That's a very good question, and I don't know a good elementary answer, but one (sketchy) answer is this: Given any conformal map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, we can ask for its Taylor series around a point, and then ask what conditions conformality imposes on its coefficients. In particular, at any fixed point, the first derivative must infinitesimally preserve the conformal structure, and so we can view it as an element of the Lie algebra of infinitesimal motions that preserve the conformal structure, which we denote $\mathfrak{co}(n)$.

Comment: When we then analyze the second derivatives of the Taylor expansion, we find that for $n = 2$ there are only weak constraints---in fact we know this must be true, because any second-degree polynomial in a complex variable is conformal except at zeros (note that $\mathfrak{co}(2) \cong \mathbb{C}$, so the connection with complex numbers for $n = 2$ is evident at the Lie algebra level). For $n > 2$, we find that $\mathfrak{co}(n)$ imposes severe constrains on second derivatives. In fact, for $n > 2$ any conformal map is determined by its value at a point and the first two derivatives there.

Comment: As for the quaternions, there are analogues of analyticity for quaternion multiplication, but the situation isn't nearly as nice as for complex numbers. One can show without much fuss that $\mathfrak{co}(3) \cong \mathbb{H}$ but this doesn't lead to any new classes of conformal maps. (This might lead to one explanation of why conformal geometry in dimension $3$ is also special, in that the appropriate curvature in this case is the Cotton tensor, and not the Weyl tensor as is the case for dimensions $> 3$.)

Comment: Thanks again @Travis for shedding light on this interesting, though quite complex (no pun intended) material. Can you recommend any litterature on the subject? Preferably starting from a level suitacle for someone with limited working knowledge of different algebras:) if you know a source that takes a tensorial approach (using real numbers) that would perfect! Thanks again

Comment: @EspenM You're welcome. There are surprisingly few texts about higher-dimensional conformal geometry. I own a copy of Akivis & Goldberg and haven't read through it in any detail but it looks reasonably good. It is "tensorial" (or a mathematician would say it is anyway), but it would be very helpful to have some familiarity with Lie groups, especially the orthogonal group and its close relatives.